# Htaccess mod_rewrite preventing execution of php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with a htaccess mod_rewrite preventing php files from being executed directly.

The site seems to be running on an MVC framework (not 100% sure on which one unfortunately) and requests are being sent through a router class. I have a subdirectory which I want to exclude from the routing and have its files be executed directly.

Here is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried excluding the subdirectory I want to execute directly with the following line but it made no difference:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdir/(.*)
```

Is there any way I can execute the php files in subdir directly? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `!^/subdir` for the pattern, instead.

Comment: Hi, I've tried !^/subdir/ with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/` ? The REQUEST_URI may start with a `/`.

Comment: I've also tried deleting the htaccess file completely, and still get an error 500. I've emailed my host to see if it's something on their end causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This line allows you to execute files directly. If you are getting error 500, check your scripts for fatal errors / uncaught exceptions